# Linq to Nhibernate - call method inside Select breaks IQueryable

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I need `IQueryable` inside my business logic assembly based on Domain entities. I want to use auto-mapper for this purposes due to big amount of similar entities.

Works:

```
_repository.GetList<AgentDto>()
        .Select(dto => new Agent{Login = dto.Login, Password = dto.Password})
        .Where(...).ToList();
```

Does not work (I could not place `Where` (another assembly) before `Select`):

```
_repository.GetList<AgentDto>()
        .Select(dto => ToAgent(dto))
        .Where(...).ToList();

private Agent ToAgent(AgentDto dto)
    {
        return new Agent{Login = dto.Login, Password = dto.Password};
    }
```

Exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was caught
  Message=CustomerInfo.Domain.Support.Agent ToAgent(CustomerInfo.DAL.DTO.AgentDto)
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMethodCallExpression(MethodCallExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitMemberExpression(MemberExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.VisitExpression(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.HqlGeneratorExpressionTreeVisitor.Visit(Expression expression, VisitorParameters parameters)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitWhereClause(WhereClause whereClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
       at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.WhereClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)
       at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitBodyClauses(ObservableCollection`1 bodyClauses, QueryModel queryModel)
       at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.Visit()
       at NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.GenerateHqlQuery(QueryModel queryModel, VisitorParameters parameters, Boolean root)
       at NHibernate.Linq.NhLinqExpression.Translate(ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory)
       at NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(String queryIdentifier, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan.CreateTranslators(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.HQLExpressionQueryPlan..ctor(String expressionStr, IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
       at NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 enabledFilters)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
       at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(IQueryExpression queryExpression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.PrepareQuery(Expression expression, IQuery& query, NhLinqExpression& nhQuery)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
       at CustomerInfo.BLL.Authentication.AgentManagementService.ValidateAgent(String agentLogin, String password) in D:\Projects\CustomerInfo\CustomerInfo.BLL\Authentication\AgentManagementService.cs:line 49
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Your method is not supported.  Namely, when NHibernate attempts to convert your 'select' into SQL it doesn't know how to translate your 'ToAgent' method.  What is wrong with your first variation as you said it works?

Answer (score 5):

You need to think about how NHibernate Linq provider works. It cannot process everything you throw at it. NHibernate's Linq provider transforms lambda expressions to HQL and eventually to SQL. There is only a limited subset of expressions that it can support. Anything you enter as an expression must be convertible to SQL and execute in the database engine itself.

NHibernate Linq provider is [extensible](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html). If you need to use some expressions that aren't supported by NH Linq provider, and you think that they can be represented in SQL, you can write your own [extension](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception).

However, your case is pretty simple. You don't need to extend NHibernate to do it. NHibernate Linq provider doesn't support your expression, but Linq to objects does. Just reverse the order in your query, and it should work as expected:

```
_repository.GetList<AgentDto>()
    .Where(...).ToList()
    .Select(dto => ToAgent(dto)).ToList();
```

`.ToList()` after `.Where()` will execute NHibernate query and return a list of `AgentDto` objects. `.Select` method after that is in fact executing as Linq to objects - on a list of `AgentDto` objects in memory.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know how things are inside. I could not use ToList() - "I need IQueryable inside my business logic". From now this question is actual only for fun, I've come to the conclusion that it's very complicated to have DTO in DAL mapped to Domain Entities with IQueryable in BLL.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you simply put the Where before the Select you'll be fine.